# Error using textarea generated in jquery and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm trying to make a site where I can reply some messages, the textarea is generated in jquery when a previous "reply" button is clicked. And then is shown a button to send the message (with Ajax), but right now I cannot get the value of the textarea, even trying with different ids, because each message has a number.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Reply messages
    $(".reply-btn").click(function() { //Clicking reply button on message list          
        var class_reply = this.className.match(/btn_(\d+)/)[1];

        $( ".panel-body" ).prepend( '<div class="main-reply-msg"></div>' );
            $( ".main-reply-msg" ).append( '<textarea class="message_replied" id="message_replied_'+class_reply+'" rows="10" cols="300" style="max-width: 100%;"></textarea>' );
        $( ".main-reply-msg" ).append( '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary reply-msg-conv" style="width:100%;" role="button">Reply</a>' );
        $( ".main-reply-msg" ).append( '<hr>' );

    $(".reply-msg-conv").click(function() { //Sending the reply
        message_replied_txt = $('.message_replied').val();
        console.log(message_replied_txt);
    });
   });
});
```

That is the code, which I'm trying to make it work, the second click works, but the textarea.val() is empty. I also tried putting the second click() outside the first, but then that click() doesn't work.

Anyone have had this problem before, because I've tried many things and nothing works.

***Update to make it more understandable:***

- The value of class_reply works fine. tested
- This function is inside onready() function.

The function works as follows:

1. List of different messages, which
   are loaded from jquery (even the html code).
2. When click on a message is shown the full message preview and a button to reply.
3. When you click on the button is loaded this function.
4. The function is loaded (the textarea and low button is shown), but when you click in the new button generated the values of the inputs (textarea and
   input fields) are not displayed any value.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it with this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'element', function(){});
```

Comment: I've tried with that inside and outside the first click() and doesn't show the textarea value. Even I've tried outside `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that something is wrong with the way you retrieve the text from the textarea.

In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jahnestacado/y3gLtLv4/1/ the only thing that I've changed is the `class_reply` variable. I gave it a fixed value. So maybe something goes wrong when you try to retrieve the matched value.
If you console.log the `clas_reply` variable what does it print?

Comment: I've tried your fiddle and works as expected, I've tried to show the class_reply and also works in my jquery, but don't show the textarea and input values entered. I don't know where can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The click event on $(".reply-msg-conv") object won't work because it is appended from run-time. You will need on function to trigger the click.

```
$(document).on("click", ".reply-msg-conv", function(){
  //your click function
})
```

Comment: Even using that the textarea and one test input are blank. The values entered don't show anything